# How to convert this loop into list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Hello i would like make list comprehension for two loops and return value from first loop. I have example:

```
rows = []
for row in value:
    for pattern, sub_pattern in zip(pattern_tag, sub_pattern_list):
        row = re.sub(pattern, sub_pattern, row)
    rows.append(row)
```

how do I make a list, through list Comprehension, so that it gives the same result

Comment: Why would you want to make this a list comprehension?

Comment: dont use the inbuild name `list` as a variable. Replace the name with something meaningful like `rows = []`

Comment: The inner for loop cannot (properly) be rephrased as a list comprehension because it fundamentally is not doing anything list-y. `substituted = [apply_substitutions(row) for row in value]`...

Comment: I wanted to know if such an implementation is possible. Since I saw many examples with nested loops, but there were none.

Comment: I'm sure the code is working. I just wanted to know about other approaches. The meaning is very simple, I need to make regexp multi-replacements. A line is rewritten in row after each replacement in the zip loop, and the already fully processed line is added to the list in the row loop.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco of course it makes sense. OP applies all the substitutions one after the other to each row and then saves the result after all substitutions.

Comment: You are naming the variable in the for loop as `row` when your 1st line of code is `for row in value`?

Comment: It is true that if the pattern has been applied, then at the next iteration of the zip loop, row will already have a new value, with which we will work further. Otherwise, it will simply be overwritten by the original row on each iteration.

Comment: Having example of input data and expected result would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you were looking for, but it's still a one-liner that makes use of the `functools.reduce` function:

```
from functools import reduce
from re import sub

rows = [
    reduce(
        lambda prev, curr: sub(*curr, prev),
        zip(pattern_tag, sub_pattern_list),
        row,
    )
    for row in value
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on *Ricardo Bucco*'s answer and *luk2302*'s comment.

List comprehensions create lists from other lists/iterables.  Every item of "source" iterable either produces one item of resulting list or is skipped (if list comprehension has `if` clause).  The order is preserved.

So your outer `for` loop can be converted to a list comprehension, since it constructs a list of replacements from a list of strings (presumably).

```
rows = [re.sub(..., ..., row) for row in value]
```

Inner `for` loop creates no list, and instead does a lot of subsequent replacements on a string, so it's not something that could be done using list comprehensions (hence _Riccardo_s' idea to use `reduce()`).